Can't create a type from an array
I'm trying to define a type for the props of a sidebar component in Vue 3 using TypeScript. Specifically, I want to create a SidebarItemProps type based on an array of objects (navLinks), which is similar to how I used to do it in React. However, I'm encountering an error from vue compiler.
<script setup lang="ts">
import { navLinks } from "@/constants/nav";

type SidebarItemProps = (typeof navLinks)[number] & { currentPath: string };

defineProps<SidebarItemProps>();
</script>

<template>
  <RouterLink
    :key="path"
    :to="path"
    :class="[
      'flex items-center justify-center lg:justify-stretch gap-3 lg:px-5 lg:py-2.5 text-sm font-semibold hover:bg-[#F5F5F7] rounded-lg-max size-10 lg:w-full transition-colors',
      currentPath === path
        ? 'text-main-black bg-[#F5F5F7]'
        : 'text-[#8E92BC] bg-white',
    ]"
  >
    <component :is="icon" class="size-6" />
    <p class="hidden lg:block">{{ title }}</p>
  </RouterLink>
</template>

That's the array:
import {
  LayoutDashboard,
  BookOpenText,
  CircleUser,
  MessageCircleMore,
  Settings,
} from "lucide-vue-next";

export const navLinks = [
  {
    icon: LayoutDashboard,
    title: "Overview",
    path: "/",
  },
  {
    icon: BookOpenText,
    title: "Tasks",
    path: "/tasks",
  },
  {
    icon: CircleUser,
    title: "Mentors",
    path: "/mentors",
  },
  {
    icon: MessageCircleMore,
    title: "Message",
    path: "/inbox",
  },
  {
    icon: Settings,
    title: "Settings",
    path: "/settings",
  },
] as const;

Error:
[plugin:vite:vue] [@vue/compiler-sfc] Failed to resolve element type from target type

/home/v/Desktop/jeret-frontend/src/components/shared/Sidebar/SidebarItem.vue
2  |  import { navLinks } from "@/constants/nav";
3  |  
4  |  type SidebarItemProps = (typeof navLinks)[number] & { currentPath: string };
   |                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
5  |  
6  |  defineProps<SidebarItemProps>();
/home/v/Desktop/jeret-frontend/src/components/shared/Sidebar/SidebarItem.vue
    at ScriptCompileContext.error (/home/v/Desktop/jeret-frontend/node_modules/@vue/compiler-sfc/dist/compiler-sfc.cjs.js:19741:11)
    at resolveArrayElementType (/home/v/Desktop/jeret-frontend/node_modules/@vue/compiler-sfc/dist/compiler-sfc.cjs.js:22315:14)
    at resolveIndexType (/home/v/Desktop/jeret-frontend/node_modules/@vue/compiler-sfc/dist/compiler-sfc.cjs.js:22274:12)
    at innerResolveTypeElements (/home/v/Desktop/jeret-frontend/node_modules/@vue/compiler-sfc/dist/compiler-sfc.cjs.js:22034:21)
    at resolveTypeElements (/home/v/Desktop/jeret-frontend/node_modules/@vue/compiler-sfc/dist/compiler-sfc.cjs.js:21995:20)
    at /home/v/Desktop/jeret-frontend/node_modules/@vue/compiler-sfc/dist/compiler-sfc.cjs.js:22028:31
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at innerResolveTypeElements (/home/v/Desktop/jeret-frontend/node_modules/@vue/compiler-sfc/dist/compiler-sfc.cjs.js:22028:20)
    at resolveTypeElements (/home/v/Desktop/jeret-frontend/node_modules/@vue/compiler-sfc/dist/compiler-sfc.cjs.js:21995:20)
    at innerResolveTypeElements (/home/v/Desktop/jeret-frontend/node_modules/@vue/compiler-sfc/dist/compiler-sfc.cjs.js:22066:16
Click outside, press Esc key, or fix the code to dismiss.
You can also disable this overlay by setting server.hmr.overlay to false in vite.config.ts.


defineProps cannot resolve type calculations like typeof (see documentation). You would have to specify the navLink type manually.
